# How can I setup an Nginx load balancer using a GET parameter?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I would like to know if it is possible to balance between two servers using a GET parameter to make decisions.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [`if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#if) statement in order to make decisions based on query parameters. However, since the [`proxy_pass` directive is not safe to use inside an `if` block](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), you need to rewrite the request to a different location. For example:

```
location /foo {
    if ($arg_test = "testing") {
        rewrite . /testing;
    }
}

location /testing {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `if` and `$request_uri`?

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri = "/s?q=test") {
        proxy_pass …
    }
}
```

However, I would advise against the above.  A better way would be to use `location` and `$arg_`, and filter based on logical requests, and not on the complete `GET` request string:

```
location = /s {
    if ($arg_q = "test") {
        proxy_pass …
    }
}
```